# How big has to be a string to interrupt the render of an innerHTML?

Tags: html, ajax, innerhtml

I would want know how much would be the limit (in bytes), or at what point **interrupts** the rendering of an innerHTML of a DOM element via innerHTML = $string or .append().

1MB, 5MB, 10MB?

I suppose depends of the browser?

In any case, how could I find that limit?

**EDIT (11/11/11):**

I create a [test](http://jsperf.com/maxsizeinnerhtml) that was iteratively added a character (letter) to an innerHTML and counted the times that jsperf added that character.

I have the next results on three browsers:

```
Avg. of max letters: | Browser
==================================================
15373                | Chrome 7.0.517.44
29148.5              | Firefox 6.0 
14285.75             | IE 8.0 (running in IE 7 mode) 
10257.75             | IE 8.0
```

I could suposse that a max of letters that a DOM element can recieve by innerHTML in an ajax request could be at most 10k in order to not interrupt the render of itself?

Or I'm totally wrong?

Comment: Every string slows down the browser proportional to its size. What you interpret as "slow" might not be what I consider slow, so that special value will be hard to find.

Comment: @Pekka I would want know how to make a method or script to take a big sample or something.

Comment: http://jsperf.com/ Probably the bigger performance hit would be constructing a string by setting `.innerHTML` over and over again.

Comment: As mentioned, define "slow". This really is a "how long is a piece of string" questions. Sorry I couldn't help myself.

Comment: @JaredFarrish I create a [test](http://jsperf.com/maxsizeinnerhtml) but I'm insecure how to take these results. I edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do it would be profile your js code. You can write a simple JS code to iteratively render it.

> You can then use the following to find the performance of your code -
>
> - In chrome - Click Tools > Developer Tools > Profile to see your JS
> - performance In Firefox - Use Firebug > Console > Profile In IE - Open
> - Developer Tools(press F12) > Profiler

This way you know the performance of your code. And you can use this in your real world application also to find bottlenecks.

However the benchmarks with a grain of salt as the performance will also depend on the machine configuration(CPU, OS etc.)